# Can't use the usual !!foo in vim // gvim on Windows 10 - missing tmp files

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, error, shell

I'm running vim // gvim 8.2 (fresh off of vim.org, and was before---just re-installed to do so as administrator, per instructions I'd missed before).

I've been getting this since getting this Windows 10 running Windows 10 + Cygwin. I also tried sending these via email to vim@vim.org (after joining) but both bounced, so I gather that's gone.

Ok, here's what's going on.  I use `!!foo` a LOT, e.g., `!!sort -u`, `!!stuff_for_calendar`, etc.  The problem is, I get the following instead (and nothing actually runs)---this is the version of the error in gvim (I got it working in normal vim while working through these examples):

```
shell returned 1

E485: Can't read file C:/Users/gamed/AppData/Local/Temp/VIolC9C.tmp
```

Note:  /bin/zsh is /bin/zsh.exe and has permissions at 777 while working on this.

Comment: You are getting that no matter the shell comamnd you run? None of them should be using the Windows temp dir. What's the environment variable TMP set to? (`:echo $TMP`). Or actually Vim may be using that as it uses a temp file during filtering....same issue though...check envvars. And what do you have for `'shelltemp'` setting? For that matter check all of the settings that start with "shell".

Comment: $TMP in zsh is set to  /cygdrive/c/Users/gamed/AppData/Local/Temp which gvim uses.
Setting it (and exporting it) does nothing...still uses the above.  Note that, after fixing this issue (it was a zsh permissions problem thanks to M$) in vim, it's only gvim that's messed up now.

Comment: Personally, I have it set to `c:\cygwin\tmp`...can't remember at the moment if I did that for cosmetic reasons or for something more significant.

Comment: Oh, and yes, no matter what shell command I run.

Comment: Also, be on the lookout for my second question, about fileformats (I'd asked about it before, and it magically fixed itself.  Well, it's back.  I couldn't post it myself (40 minute rule) so it should post on its own sometime while I'm having dinner once that 40 minute limit is passed..

Comment: You can try debugging things by doing something like `:let &shell = 'c:\cygwin\bin\zsh.exe -x'` and/or `:set verbose=5`. The latter will show the redirections of a filter operation.

Comment: Check your shell options. In particular, what your shell is. `/bin/zsh` may not be resolvable for a native windows application like windows gvim.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I've edited your question to narrow in on the important bits. Please also try to avoid (even thinly concealed) profane or rude language. You might wish to take a look at the [Code of Conduct](https://vi.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: Thanks for the (I'll take them as back-dated <grin>) welcome to vi (1985) and vim (ca 1994?).  Yeah, I've been using vi since 1985 and vim since it was very, very young (I think I found out about it from a post on comp.sources.unix.

Good point on the shell vs Windows.  I'll test that now.  Result:  I'm about to answer this question.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Confusing....am I sure I want to answer my question?  Thanks to the comment from Christian that led me straight to the answer, I am, yes!

I did the following in a zsh window:

```
export SHELL=C:/cygwin64/bin/zsh.exe
```

That fixed it.  So I'll be adding that to my `~/.zprofile`.